# dynamically divs creation on the basis of table records

Tags: php, html, css

I have a page in which i have to display a list of job boards. I have a table named as job_board in which i all the record of 10 to 12 may be more job boards is saved. I want to display a page in which there will be a div as container and inside that div i want to display these job boards, each in a separate div(side by side). At the moment i am trying this loop:

```
  foreach($this->test as $value)
{
            $variable=null;

             echo $variable .='<div class="testing"></div><div class="head"></div>';
              $variable .=$value["job_board_id"] . '</br>';
              $variable .=$value["name"] . '</br>';
              $variable .=$value["description"] . '</br>';
              $variable .=$value["price"]. '</br>';
              $variable .= $value["enabled"]. '</br>';

              echo $variable;
}
```

The columns in my table are id,name,description,price,url) 
I want to display it in the small divs which are inside the main div "container"

Comment: You can use float:left or clear:both property while creating divs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want show divs side by side, please try `float`. The code may goes like this:

```
foreach($this->test as $value)
{
          $variable=null;
          $variable .='<div class="cell">';
          $variable .=$value["job_board_id"] . '</br>';
          $variable .=$value["name"] . '</br>';
          $variable .=$value["description"] . '</br>';
          $variable .=$value["price"]. '</br>';
          $variable .= $value["enabled"]. '</br>';
          $variable .='</div>';
          echo $variable;
}
```

And, the class 'cell' will be defined in your CSS file like below:

```
<style type="text/css">
.cell{
    width:150px;
    float:left;
}
#container:after { /*clear the float*/
    visibility: hidden;
    display: block;
    font-size: 0;
    content: " ";
    clear: both;
    height: 0;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you wish to print each line in one div with span you can try with this

```
 echo $variable .='<div class="testing"></div><div class="head"></div>';
              $variable .= '<div><span>'.$value["job_board_id"] . '</span>';
              $variable .= '<span>'.$value["name"] . '</span>';
              $variable .= '<span>'.$value["description"] . '</span>';
              $variable .= '<span>'.$value["price"]. '</span>';
              $variable .= '<span>'.$value["enabled"]. '</span></div>';

              echo $variable;
```

And for second loop after print `$variable` please assign with blank like `$variable = ''`;

Also try to make more attractive with css.

let me know if i can help you further.